# "conda env list" always returns "y/N" and neither answer returns anything, yet "conda info --envs" works perfectly?

Tags: conda

After moving miniconda3 to another path, and after fixing all paths in:

a, **~/.bashrc**
b, **~/bin/activate**
c, **~/bin/conda**
d, **~/etc/profile.d/conda.sh**

I have a working conda and all my installations have been preserved. The only things that work abnormally are:

1. `conda env list` returns `y/N` and neither the answer returns my env list, yet `conda info --envs` works perfectly and returns all my env names.
2. `pip --version` returns an error message

> bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Can anyone tell me, besides the four files above, if there is any file that I need to modify?

The list of files that might be related:

- ~/miniconda3/condabin/conda
- ~/miniconda3/bin/conda
- ~/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
- ~/miniconda3/bin/activate
- ~/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
- ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
- ~/miniconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
- ~/miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
- ~/miniconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
- ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
- ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
- ~/.bashrc

Comment: One of the crucial issues with moving a Conda installation is that some dynamically-linked libraries unfortunately use absolute paths (determined at package installation time). In your case, it is possible that `pip` and `conda-env` rely on such libraries. The Anaconda team developed the `conda-prefix-replacement` tool for rewriting these absolute paths. This was originally applied for Mac OS X users upgrading to 10.15+, which broke the old default Anaconda installation path (`/anaconda{2,3}`). However, you may need to use it to repair your packages.

Comment: I would uninstall and start from the beginning. This shouldn't be this complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually modify this file: `/newpath/miniconda3/bin/conda-env` change the first line to new position.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to modify your new path in ./bin/pip and ./bin/conda-env

Comment: Perhaps this quip is better converted into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

conda init

this command can solve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).